# Text Engine for the Backend Which Outputs an Image

Tags: layout, text

I am looking for a server-side text engine which can generate images with the specified text.  I have experience with CoreText on iOS, and I am looking for a similar text layout and rendering engine to use on a server.  Ideally this is open source and could be run on Linux.

Comment: Want to violate site rules? Just throw a bounty on your question and prevent flagging.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php#refsect1-function.imagestring-examples should get you started

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify many requirements regarding what kind of input and output you need, but a (La)TeX to image server should fit the requirement of

> server-side text engine which can generate images with the specified text

To that end, you can use [mathoid](https://github.com/wikimedia/mathoid) (a node based server).

While LaTeX is usually used for math-related typesetting, it can be used to typeset arbitrary text and results in very high-quality output.

There are other command-line utilities that convert LaTeX to images, but those would need to be wrapped in a server somehow.  For example [tex2png](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/tex2png/).

Comment: Does Latex have colors now? Did not have in 1993 when I wrote my diploma thesis with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is using [`gd`](https://boutell.com/gd/) (and [here](https://libgd.github.io/)), which has a command-line utility called `fly` allowing you to describe an image in terms of simple primitives (line, rectangle, colour) and include text using TrueType fonts.

If this is to be integrated into, say, a Webserver, then e.g. PHP has bindings for GD2 and can be used straight away.

A more typesetting-oriented approach could be [Sile](http://sile-typesetter.org/what-is/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness in case someone is having a similar issue:

I'm one of the authors of [LaTeX Render Server](https://github.com/vsfexperts/LaTeX). We did have similar issues and created this project as a result. Basically, the service is offering a REST endpoint, which will accept raw latex code and return a rendered pdf as a result. The url is immutable, so it could be referenced in some other document/application. This service is meant to be used as a microservice in some intranet environment. There's no authentication, which could be addressed by using a reverse proxy in front of it (recommended to address loadbalancing/failover).